# multiple type with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have that object that I want to use as a type:

```
interface MyInput {
    id: string,
    label: string,
    setter: Function,
    type: string,
    value: string | string[] | boolean,
    options?: string[]
}
```

I have some errors like:

> *Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | string[]'.*
> *Type 'string | boolean | string[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.*

The thing is that I will always know whether my value is string[], boolean or string with my type property.

Is there any solution to remove those errors without make 3 different interfaces?

Beside putting my value property to any or to create 3 diffent types, I do not known.

Comment: `The thing is that I will always know whether my value is string[], boolean or string with my type property.` Can you be more specific? What do you (the human) look for to tell which it will be?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will need to do something to cast it or annotate it with a `@ts-ignore`.  e.g.

```
(input.value as string[]).map(...
```

Comment: And why shouldn't we check for this at runtime?

Comment: You would and the question said they know the type to make the discrimination, but you still need to do a cast (or fundamentally change the data structure like the other answer)

Answer (score 1):

You may define the interface with generic type, as in below code

```js
interface MyInput<T = string | string[] | boolean> {
    id?: string,
    label?: string,
    setter?: Function,
    type?: string,
    value: T,
    options?: string[]
}
```

The actual type can be determined while defining variable, as in below code

```js
let ip: MyInput<string[]> = {
    value: []
}

ip.value.map((v) => {...})
```